# Handling Click-Aways for two or more of the same directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to create click-away functionality for an AngularJS directive (ie. when the user doesn't click a certain element, it hides).

I'm adding an event to $(body) which detects a click.

I then check whether either my directive or any of it's children have been clicked. If they haven't, it hides a div.

This works fine when I have one directive, but the moment I add a second of the same kind, it's the second that handles the $(body).click() event. The first doesn't get a look-in.

My code is as follows (I've removed much of it):

```
angular.module('ma.directives')
    .directive('maDropdownPanel', function () {

        var directiveId = null;

        return {
            restrict: "E",  
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: "maDropdownPanel.html",
            scope: {},  
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

                $('body').on('click', scope.handleClickAway);

                // Get an ID unique to this particular directive.
                directiveId = "ma-dropdown-panel" + scope.$id;    
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.handleClickAway = function (event) {
                    // The following shows which directive took it. Out of two, it's always the second (ie. the last to register the event).
                    console.log(directiveId);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I feel like if I can get the right one to be called, I can handle the rest.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Multiple things you need to be aware of for the click-away function. First adding the `click` on the body means it will always be fired no matter where you click. This is because the event bubbles from the body, to the element, then back to the body. Secondly the `click` event that you are registering needs to be removed at some point or till will exist forever and always be getting evaluated.

Comment: @Enzey thanks. Are you aware of any other way of handling it besides adding the click to the body?

Comment: No, that is the way you need to do it but you need extra processing to ignore certain elements. If you are registering a 1 time event you could look at using https://github.com/EnzeyNet/Services/blob/master/src/nzEventHelper.js#L95 If this is something you want to keep running then you could still use it an re-register the event each time or use it as an example for your own use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it. Enzey's comment provided the clue:

> Secondly the click event that you are registering needs to be removed at some point or till will exist forever and always be getting evaluated.

The key was to:

1. Register the click event when the div is shown.
2. Remove the click event when the div is hidden.

Because a click-away hides the div:

- There is no chance more than one div will be visible at one time.
- That means there will only ever be one relevant click event registered at one time.
- And that means there are no clashes between different click events/directives.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that make that directive event to specific `click` by appending click event name like `click.panelClick1` & it would be specific to each element, pass the slug parameter using attribute, but you need change that value each time you make directive

**OR**

Another good approach would be define that slug parameter for uniqueness of click event by doing something like `Math.Random()` function which will return random value.

**Html**

```
<ma-dropdown-panel slug="1"></ma-dropdown-panel>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('ma.directives')
    .directive('maDropdownPanel', function() {

        var directiveId = null;

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: "maDropdownPanel.html",
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                $('body').on('click.panelClick' + attributes.slug, scope.handleClickAway);

                // Get an ID unique to this particular directive.
                directiveId = "ma-dropdown-panel" + scope.$id;
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.handleClickAway = function(event) {
                    // The following shows which directive took it. Out of two, it's always the second (ie. the last to register the event).
                    console.log(directiveId);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ooh. I didn't know about name spacing the event name. I'll give that a try next time I'm in front of my computer, thanks!

Comment: @greggannicott let me know if anything is there

Comment: did you able to run my approach.?

Comment: it didn't work, unfortunately. It didn't appear to separate events between directives like I was hoping. Perhaps with a bit more persisting, it might have worked (I might have been doing it wrong), but I found a different solution. Thanks for the suggestion though! Appreciated.