# Creating a 'tab-away' attribute Directive with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm asking this question off the back of:

[Dynamically adding an attribute Directive to a transclude Directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018941/dynamically-adding-an-attribute-directive-to-a-transclude-directive-in-angularjs)

where it was pointed out that the way I was attempting to do something was likely the wrong way to do it. Given that I'm newish to AngularJS, I probably am.

## This is what I'm looking to achieve, and how I'm going about it.

If anyone can suggest a more appropriate way - using AngularJS - I'd appreciate it.

### The Initial Control/Directive

I'm creating a dropdown panel control using a transcluded directive. It has a button. When you press the button, a div will become visible. The div will contain the transcluded content. I'm fine with all of this.

### Tabbing Away

I needed to add functionality so that if you tab away from the control, it closes.

First of all, I attach a 'keypress' event to the document body. This is attached when the dropdown is displayed, and removed when the dropdown is hidden. It must be added/removed at this point to avoid conflict with other instances of the directive (see [Handling Click-Aways for two or more of the same directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831637/handling-click-aways-for-two-or-more-of-the-same-directive), which discusses click away, but the scope issues also apply for keypress events).

I then check whether the control has lost focus. To do this, I check whether the directive itself, along with any of it's children has focus following a key press which is tab. The blur logic is as follows:

```
$scope.directiveHasLostFocus = function () {
  var dropdownWrapper = angular.element("#" + $scope.directiveId + " .dropdown-panel-wrapper");
  if (!dropdownWrapper.is(":focus") && dropdownWrapper.find(":focus").length === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This all works fine.

### Refactoring

All the code for this directive is in one directive. It's growing...

I had the thought that I could extract the tab-away functionality into it's own directive.

To do that, I needed to dynamically add/remove the new tab-away directive when the dropdown panel is displayed/hidden (so the events are added/removed appropriately). And that's what led me to:

[Dynamically adding an attribute Directive to a transclude Directive in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018941/dynamically-adding-an-attribute-directive-to-a-transclude-directive-in-angularjs)

... where I was told I am probably doing it wrong.

Can anyone suggest a better way of going about this using AngularJS? I could not extract it into it's own directive, and it would work fine. But I'm keen to extract it if I can.

Sorry it's such a vague question. I prefer to ask more focused questions, but on this occasion it has to be somewhat high level.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why does your tab-away directive need to be removed from the dom element?  What about having the tab-away directive accept some type of parameter indicating whether it is currently active.  It could then $watch that parameter to add/remove it's hooks.

Comment: Hey I like that. I'll give that a try, thanks.